# The best way recognizing similarity of list lengths

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a *dict* containing lists under its keys:

```
dct = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
       'b': [1, 2, 3, 4],
       'c': [1, 2]}
```

What is the best way to recognize whether the length of the lists are **the same** or not?

This is my solution:

```
import itertools
len(set(itertools.imap(len, dct.viewvalues()))) == 1
```

`True` if similar  and `False` if not

UPD: In reference to @RaymondHettinger advice replace `map` to `itertools.imap`

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you mean similar or the same?

Comment: I think you mean `values` instead of `viewvalues`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski as far as i'm concerned using `viewvalues` is more *pythonic* than `values` according to [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)

Comment: @klesh  Didn't realize that `values` has the name `viewvalues` in 2.7.  In Python 3 `values` returns a view object and there is no `viewvalues` method.  Prior to 2.7 you would use `itervalues` if you wanted to avoid creating a intermediate list.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution looks fine.

If you want to tweek it a bit, use *itertools.imap()* instead of *map()*.  That will collapse the memory footprint to O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: what can you say about the solution with *generator expression* below?

Comment: The genexp is also nice and it confers the same memory saving benefit as imap(), but map/imap runs faster because the global lookup of len() is done just once.

Comment: How is it O(1)? If all n lists have different lengths, the set uses O(n) memory. It could be done in O(1) space by combining imap, groupby, and islice.

Comment: @Michael I have added another answer which uses `imap` and `groupby`. Please, check it, if you feel like. I have no idea, how you meant using `islice`.

Answer (score 5):

First, I would stick with `itervalues`, which uses easy evaluation.

Second, I would be wary of relying on using `set` since it performs looking up the value in the set on every iteration of going through dictionary. It's `O(1)` on the overage (and `O(n)` in the worse case which is `O(1)` in our case if all the length are the same, and `O(n)` if all the length are different) according to the [docs](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). But it's difficult to asses the overhead of using set.

I would use `all` in this case. `all` fails when it finds the first `False` value. So, the first mismatch of the length would stop the interating process. While, if using `set`, it would go through **all the list** to the end and only then compare its length to `1`.

```
>>> dct = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
       'b': [1, 2, 3, 4],
       'c': [1, 2]}
>>> lenght_1 = len(dct.itervalues().next())
>>> all(len(value)==lenght_1 for value in dct.itervalues())
False

>>> dct = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
       'b': [1, 2, 4],
       'c': [1, 2, 5]}
>>> lenght_1 = len(dct.itervalues().next())
>>> all(len(value)==lenght_1 for value in dct.itervalues())
True
```

The code can be optimized by using the same iterator `it` which will not go through the first value twice:

```
>>> it = dct.itervalues()
>>> length_1 = len(next(it))
>>> all(len(value)==l1 for value in it)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note: [ovgolovin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826428/the-best-way-recognizing-similarity-of-lists-lenght/7827203#7827203) is much better. I'm leaving this answer here because there's discussion that refers to it.*

Your solution is fine, but you could use a generator expression which uses less memory and is more readable:

```
len(set(len(x) for x in dct.viewvalues()))) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As Michael J. Barber suggested in the comments to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826428/the-best-way-recognizing-similarity-of-list-lengths/7826512#7826512), here's the code which uses [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module.

`imap` just applies the `len` function to every list.

`groupby` just gropes the values in chunks of the same lengths.

So, if there is more than one chunk of length, the lengths are different. If there is only one chuck of lengths, it means, the lengths of the lists are the same, and the second access to the `groupby` iterator should yield `StopIteration` thus returning `None` (the default value of the `next` function).

The great benefit of this code is that `imap` and `groupby` are written in C and they are pretty fast.

```
from itertools import imap,groupby

dct = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
       'b': [1, 2, 3, 4],
       'c': [1, 2]}

dct2 = {'a': [1, 2, 3],
       'b': [1, 2, 34],
       'c': [1, 2, 5]}

def check_lenghts(iterable):
    it = groupby(imap(len,iterable.itervalues()))
    next(it,None)
    return True if next(it,None)==None else False

print(check_lenghts(dct))
print(check_lenghts(dct2))
```

Comment: Why I mentioned `islice`: you can use `islice` to limit the iterator created by `groupby` to having a length of at most two. Here, you could replace the `next` calls in `check_lengths` by `len(list(islice(it, 2)) < 2`. Overall, I think your other answer is probably clearer.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber On the other hand, the `groupby` will go trough all the values of the second length before yielding the second value (and if the list has the first value of length 1 and the rest say 1 million values of length 2, the `groupby` will pass all million values of length 2. But using `all` function as in the other answer will have only to access the first value of the length-2 list to return `False`.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber I had a closer look at the `groupby` pure Python equivalent. The value is yielded by `groupby` at the very moment the new `key` value is reached. So, if the real C code carries the same behavior, then there will be no passing to the end of the second length chunk thus reaching the same efficiency as the version with `all`.

Comment: You can try it out in the interpreter: it does work just like the pure Python version.